# How to call the function it's in?

Tags: python, function, loops

I am creating a Python script which is calling the Instagram API and creating an array  of all the photos.  The API results are paginated, so it only shows 25 results.  If there are more photos, it gives you a `next_url` which contains the next batch.

I have the script made in PHP, and I am doing something like this in my function:

```
// loop through this current function again with the next batch of photos
if($data->pagination->next_url) :
  $func = __FUNCTION__;
  $next_url = json_decode(file_get_contents($data->pagination->next_url, true));
  $func($next_url);
endif;
```

How can I do something like this in Python?

My function looks sort of like this:

```
def add_images(url):

if url['pagination']['next_url']:
  try:
    next_file = urllib2.urlopen(url['pagination']['next_url'])
    next_json = f.read()
  finally:
    # THIS DOES NOT WORK
    next_url = json.loads(next_json)
    add_images(next_url)
 return
```

But obviously I can't just call add_images() from within.  What are my options here?

Comment: *"But obviously I can't just call add_images() from within."* Why not? It should work.

Comment: Drive a while loop with the presence of next_json.

Comment: You can certainly do that, it's valid recursion. Watch the scoping of your variables and be careful of stack overflows...

Comment: calling itself until condition is met is called `recursion`;

Comment: Yep - Scrapy, a Python web scraping framework actually heavily relies on this sort of recursion to make processing web pages repeatable and easy. It might be worth checking out Scrapy and/or Requests

Comment: Probably your code is not working because you are using `try...finally` improperly (e.g.: you are receiving an exception before `next_json` gets assigned).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `add_images()` from within `add_images()`. Last time I checked, recursion still works in Python ;-).

However, since Python does not support tail call elimination, you need to be wary of stack overflows. The default recursion limit for CPython is 1,000 (available via [`sys.getrecursionlimit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit)), so you probably don't need to worry.

However, nowadays with generators and the advent of [`async`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) I'd consider such JavaScript style recursive callback calls *unpythonic*. You might instead consider using generators and/or coroutines:

```
def get_images(base_url):
   url = base_url

   while url:
       with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(url)) as url_file:
           json_data = url_file.read()
       # get_image_urls() extracts the images from JSON and returns an iterable.
       # python 3.3 and up have "yield from" 
       # (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)
       for img_url in get_image_urls(json_data):
           yield img_url
       # dict.get() conveniently returns None or
       # the provided default argument when the 
       # element is missing.
       url = json_data.get('pagination', {}).get('next_url')

images = list(get_images(base_url));
```